Error: Undefined mixin in SCSS when upgrading Angular 14 to Angular 18
I am upgrading my project from Angular 14 to Angular 18, and I'm encountering an error related to an undefined SCSS mixin when running the build. The error message I receive is:


./src/scss/angular.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
9  │ ┌         @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
10 │ │             margin: (-$app-content-padding-y-sm) (-$app-content-padding-x-sm);
11 │ │             padding: $app-content-padding-y-sm $app-content-padding-x-sm;
12 │ └         }
   ╵
  src/scss/default/app/_app-content.scss 9:3  @import
  src/scss/default/_app.scss 1:9              @import
  src/scss/default/styles.scss 12:9           @import
  src/scss/angular.scss 1:9                   root stylesheet



What I've Tried:
1. Upgrade Process: This issue started occurring after upgrading from Angular 14 to Angular 18.
2. Ensured that Bootstrap is correctly imported: Here's my angular.scss file:


@import 'default/styles';
@import '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';



3. Checked the versions:
My package.json includes the following dependencies:


"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/localize": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/material": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^18.2.0",
  "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.2",
  "@angular/cli": "^18.2.2",
  "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.1",
  "sass-loader": "^16.0.1",
  "typescript": "^5.5.2"
}



4. Ensured the SCSS mixins are correctly imported: The mixins, such as media-breakpoint-down, are not recognized despite importing Bootstrap's mixins.
5. Attempted fixes:

Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json.
Cleared NPM cache using npm cache clean --force.
Reinstalled dependencies with npm install.
Tried different versions of sass-loader and mini-css-extract-plugin.

None of these steps resolved the issue.
Additional Information:

Angular CLI Version: 18.2.2
Node Version: 20.17.0
NPM Version: 10.8.2

Question:
What could be causing the Undefined mixin error for SCSS mixins like media-breakpoint-down(md) in my Angular 18 project, and how can I resolve this issue after upgrading from Angular 14?
